# How to check if we're at the end of the ListView using StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, stream-builder

I'm fetching data from my database using `streambuilder`. It's working fine but at the end of the listView it's showing me red screen.
Is there any way to check if we're at the end of the list and automatically close the controller or something like this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is the error it's showing me
`Another exception was thrown: FormatException: Invalid number (at character 1)`

````
  List<Repas> listRepas = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    streamControllerRepas = StreamController.broadcast();
    streamControllerRepas.stream.listen((P) {
      setState(() {
        listRepas.add(P);
      });
    });
    loadRepas(streamControllerRepas);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    streamControllerRepas?.close();
    streamControllerRepas = null;
  }

loadRepas(StreamController sc) async {
    String url = "http://bonbizfood.com/foodios/php/get_repas_all.php";
    var client = new http.Client();
    var req = new http.Request('get', Uri.parse(url));

    var streamedRes = await client.send(req);
    streamedRes.stream
        .transform(utf8.decoder)
        .transform(json.decoder)
        .expand((e) => e)
        .map((map) => Repas.fromJsonMap(map))
        .pipe(streamControllerRepas)
        .whenComplete(() {
      streamControllerRepas?.close();
      streamControllerRepas = null;
    });
  }

@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: RefreshIndicator(
          child: ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              //physics: FixedExtentScrollPhysics(),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0),
              //itemCount: listRepas.length == null ? 0 : listRepas.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                  _makeElementT(index)),
          onRefresh: _refresh),
    );
  }

  Widget _makeElementT(int index) {
    if (index >= listRepas.length) {
      return null;
    }
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0),
      child: InkWell(
        child: listRepas[index].img != ''
            ? Card(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2.8),
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                DetailRepasPage(list1: listRepas, index: index),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            height: (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3.45),
                            child: Padding(
                              padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                              child: CachedNetworkImage(
                                imageUrl: listRepas[index].img,
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                placeholder: (context, url) => new Center(
                                      child: Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                                        child: SpinKitPulse(
                                          color: Colors.amber,
                                          size: 60.0,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                errorWidget: (context, url, error) => new Icon(
                                      Icons.dashboard,
                                      color: Colors.grey,
                                      size: 70,
                                    ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, left: 4),
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Icon(Icons.favorite,
                                  color: Colors.black38, size: 24),
                              onTap: () {

                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                              top: 4,
                              right: 4,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                                elevation: 4.0,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                  child: Wrap(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Image.asset(
                                        'assets/icons/ic_timer.png',
                                        height: 14,
                                        width: 14,
                                      ),
                                      Text(listRepas[index].tempspreparation,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black38,
                                              fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                              fontSize: 12)),
                                      Text(' - ',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black38,
                                              fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                              fontSize: 12)),
                                      Text(
                                          (int.parse('${listRepas[index].tempspreparation}') +
                                                  20)
                                              .toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black38,
                                              fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                              fontSize: 12)),
                                      Text(' min',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black38,
                                              fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                              letterSpacing: 0,
                                              fontSize: 12)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Positioned(
                              top: 2,
                              left: 30,
                              child: InkWell(
                                child: Card(
                                  color: listRepas[index].vegetarien == 'Oui'
                                      ? Colors.green
                                      : Colors.redAccent,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                                  elevation: 4.0,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 20,
                                      height: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  if (listRepas[index].vegetarien == "Oui") {
                                    Toast.show(
                                        'Ce menu est végétarien', context,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                        duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                  } else {
                                    Toast.show(
                                        "Ce menu n'est pas végétarien", context,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                        duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                  }
                                },
                              )),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 25,
                            left: 4,
                            child: Text(listRepas[index].nom,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontFamily: 'ThasaB')),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 8,
                            left: 4,
                            child: Wrap(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(listRepas[index].prix.toString(),
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black45,
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontFamily: 'Thasa')),
                                Text(' f cfa',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black45,
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontFamily: 'Thasa'))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 4,
                            right: 4,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 80,
                              height: 30,
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  child: new Wrap(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Icon(
                                        Icons.shopping_cart,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: 15,
                                      ),
                                      new Text(
                                        'Ajouter',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12.0,
                                            fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    ItemPanier cartItem = new ItemPanier(
                                      listRepas[index].codearticle,
                                      listRepas[index].nom,
                                      int.parse('${listRepas[index].prix}'),
                                      listRepas[index].ingredients,
                                      listRepas[index].coderesto,
                                      listRepas[index].nomresto,
                                      listRepas[index].contactresto,
                                      listRepas[index].positionGPS,
                                      listRepas[index].typearticle,
                                      listRepas[index].conditionnement,
                                      listRepas[index].tempspreparation,
                                      listRepas[index].description,
                                      listRepas[index].img,
                                      listRepas[index].afficheimg,
                                      listRepas[index].topmenu,
                                      listRepas[index].slider,
                                      listRepas[index].heure_fermeture,
                                      int.parse('1'),
                                      int.parse('${listRepas[index].prix}'),
                                      listRepas[index].heure_ouverture,
                                      listRepas[index].prix_barre,
                                      listRepas[index].codecategorie,
                                      listRepas[index].vegetarien,
                                      listRepas[index].desactiver,
                                    );
                                    _saveCart(context, cartItem);
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            : Card(
                child: SizedBox(
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: 70,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 0, left: 0),
                    child: InkWell(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) =>
                                DetailRepasPage(list1: listRepas, index: index),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 4, left: 4),
                            child: InkWell(
                              child: Icon(Icons.favorite,
                                  color: Colors.black38, size: 24),
                              onTap: () {
                                });
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                              top: 2,
                              left: 30,
                              child: InkWell(
                                child: Card(
                                  color: listRepas[index].vegetarien == 'Oui'
                                      ? Colors.green
                                      : Colors.redAccent,
                                  shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                                  elevation: 4.0,
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 20,
                                      height: 20,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                onTap: () {
                                  if (listRepas[index].vegetarien == "Oui") {
                                    Toast.show(
                                        'Ce menu est végétarien', context,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                                        duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                  } else {
                                    Toast.show(
                                        "Ce menu n'est pas végétarien", context,
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
                                        duration: Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                  }
                                },
                              )),
                          Positioned(
                              top: 4,
                              right: 4,
                              child: Card(
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0)),
                                elevation: 4.0,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
                                  child: Wrap(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Image.asset(
                                        'assets/icons/ic_timer.png',
                                        height: 14,
                                        width: 14,
                                      ),
                                      Text(listRepas[index].tempspreparation,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black38,
                                              fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                              fontSize: 12)),
                                      Text(' - ',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black38,
                                              fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                              fontSize: 12)),
                                      Text(
                                          (int.parse('${listRepas[index].tempspreparation}') +
                                                  20)
                                              .toString(),
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black38,
                                              fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                              fontSize: 12)),
                                      Text(' min',
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black38,
                                              fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                              letterSpacing: 0,
                                              fontSize: 12)),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 25,
                            left: 4,
                            child: Text(listRepas[index].nom,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black45,
                                    fontSize: 17,
                                    fontFamily: 'ThasaB')),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 8,
                            left: 4,
                            child: Wrap(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(listRepas[index].prix,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black45,
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontFamily: 'Thasa')),
                                Text(' f cfa',
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        color: Colors.black45,
                                        fontSize: 15,
                                        fontFamily: 'Thasa'))
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                          Positioned(
                            bottom: 4,
                            right: 4,
                            child: SizedBox(
                              width: 80,
                              height: 30,
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  shape: new RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                      borderRadius:
                                          new BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                  padding: new EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  child: new Wrap(
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        WrapCrossAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      new Icon(
                                        Icons.shopping_cart,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        size: 15,
                                      ),
                                      new Text(
                                        'Ajouter',
                                        style: new TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 12.0,
                                            fontFamily: 'Thasa',
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
        onTap: () {
        },
      ),
    );
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You commented out the itemCount property. This is how your listview.builder knows it's at the end of the list. Otherwise it'll keep building to no end. If you're at the end of the data stream and you keep building widgets with this data the data will be null and that will throw an error at the end of the list - which is what you're seeing.

Comment: knowing where your error is showing up would be quite helpful considering you've put a *lot* of code in the question.

Comment: Also, that error you have shown here is a secondary error. Note the "Another exception..." part. Meaning you have other errors before the one you mention.